# Is there a built in min function for a slice of int arguments or a variable number of int arguments in golang?

Tags: go

Is there a built in function that returns the minimum of a slice of int arguments:

```
func MinIntSlice(v []int) (m int) {
    if len(v) > 0 {
        m = v[0]
    }
    for i := 1; i < len(v); i++ {
        if v[i] < m {
            m = v[i]
        }
    }
    return
}
```

OR the minimum of a variable number of int arguments:

```
func MinIntVarible(v1 int, vn ...int) (m int) {
    m = v1
    for i := 0; i < len(vn); i++ {
        if vn[i] < m {
            m = vn[i]
        }
    }
    return
}
```

If not, is the best "convention" simply to create a package that contains helpers like this?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

*Edit: This answer is out of date. There are now built-in functions `min` and `max` in Go as of 1.21. See [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76531109).*

There is no built-in for this.

If you need this functionality only in one package you can write an un-exported function (e.g. `minIntSlice`).

If you need this functionality in multiple packages you can create a package and put similar functions there. You should consider making this package internal (https://golang.org/s/go14internal).

A few suggestions how to improve your code:

1. `MinIntSlice` will return 0 for an empty slice. However 0 is a valid min element as well. I think calling panic on an empty slice is a better option.
2. Use range loop:

   ```
    for i, e := range v {
        if i==0 || e < m {
            m = e
        }
    }
   ```

by not giving the index of value it will give you the minimum value 0, which may not be present in given values, so you also have to apply condition on index.

Comment: That is a helpful piece of feedback. I had not as of yet been exposed to "range".

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to "internal" packages. I do have duplicated unexported functions like this, and internal looks like the way to better maintain these.

Comment: This answer is out of date. There are now built-in functions `min` and `max` in Go as of 1.21. See [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76531109).

Answer (score 21):

As of Go `1.21` there are now built-in functions to get the `max` and `min` for a given number of arguments as well as a new `slices` package to achieve the same for slices.

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Min_and_max

```golang
min(2, -5, 8, 1.2) // Result: -5
max(2, -5, 8, 1.2) // Result: 8
```

For slices, use the `slices` package:
https://pkg.go.dev/slices

```golang
import "slices"
```

```golang
x := []float64{2, -5, 8, 1.2}
slices.Min(x) // Result: -5
slices.Max(x) // Result: 8
```

Comment: Is there a way to get an index? Have I missed something in the docs or is the design of it a bit questionable?

Answer (score 19):

As @kostya correctly stated there is no built-in min or max function in Golang.

However, I would suggest a slightly different solution:

```
func MinMax(array []int) (int, int) {
    var max int = array[0]
    var min int = array[0]
    for _, value := range array {
        if max < value {
            max = value
        }
        if min > value {
            min = value
        }
    }
    return min, max
}
```

By that the problem of an empty slice is solved: a runtime error shows up (`index out of range`) and the max value is for free. :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
    min := s[0]
    for i :=1; i < len(s); i++ {
        if min > s[i] {
            min = s[i]
        }
    }
```

> `min > s[i]? min = s[i] : min`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't care about input array

```
import . "sort"
func MinIntSlice(v []int){
    Ints(v)
    return z[0]
}

func MaxIntSlice(v []int){
    Ints(v)
    return z[len(v)-1]
}
// and MinMax version
func MinMax(v []int)(int,int){
    Ints(v)
    return z[0],z[len(v)-1]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This package](https://github.com/adam-lavrik/go-imath) contains some implementations of `Min` and `Max` functions for separate values or slices. After `go get` it can be used like:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "<Full URL>/go-imath/ix" // Functions for int type
)
...
fmt.Println(ix.Min(100, 152)) // Output: 100
fmt.Println(ix.Mins(234, 55, 180)) // Output: 55
fmt.Println(ix.MinSlice([]int{2, 29, 8, -1})) // Output: -1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no function for such operation in the standard packages.

However, the [gonum library](https://www.gonum.org/) offers the functions `floats.Min(x)` and `floats.Max(x)` (and other interesting functions for manipulation of numerical data).

Usage:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gonum.org/v1/gonum/floats"
)

func main() {
    x := []float64{1, 6, 9, -3, -5}
    minX := floats.Min(x)
    maxX := floats.Max(x)
    fmt.Printf("Min: %f, max %f\n", minX, maxX)
}
```

Results:

```
Min: -5.000000, max 9.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

For huge slices containing millions of items (for example a 25 megapixel image as `[]int`) you can get significant performance gains by calculating min/max in chunks:

```golang
func GetMinMax(data []int) (int, int) {
    minVal := data[0]
    maxVal := data[0]
    for i := range data {
        if data[i] < minVal {
            minVal = data[i]
        }

        if data[i] > maxVal {
            maxVal = data[i]
        }
    }

    return minVal, maxVal
}

func GetMinMaxConcurrent(data []int) (int, int) {
    numChan := make(chan int)

    numChunks := runtime.NumCPU()
    chunkSize := len(data) / numChunks

    // Process
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < numChunks; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i, chunkSize int, numChan chan int) {
            startIndex := i * chunkSize
            endIndex := startIndex + chunkSize
            if endIndex > len(data) {
                endIndex = len(data)
            }

            minVal, maxVal := GetMinMax(data[startIndex:endIndex])
            numChan <- minVal
            numChan <- maxVal
            wg.Done()
        }(i, chunkSize, numChan)
    }

    // Collect results
    resultsChan := make(chan int)
    defer close(resultsChan)

    go func(numChan, resultsChan chan int) {
        arr := make([]int, 0)
        for num := range numChan {
            arr = append(arr, num)
        }
        minVal, maxVal := GetMinMax(arr)
        resultsChan <- minVal
        resultsChan <- maxVal
    }(numChan, resultsChan)

    wg.Wait()
    close(numChan) // needed so results routine can return

    return <-resultsChan, <-resultsChan
}
```

This code is not performant for small slices, only use if your slice is big enough to benefit from processing chunks concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

With sorting it can be shorter:

```go
func MinIntSlice(v []int) int {
  sort.Ints(v)
  return v[0]
}

func MaxIntSlice(v []int) int {
  sort.Ints(v)
  return v[len(v)-1]
}
```

But don't forget to modify it for zero length slices on your taste.

Comment: Mutating the underlying slice just to pick something is a terrible idea.  This could change assertions about the implicit ordering elsewhere

Comment: sorting is o(n log n) but maximum is a linear time o(n) algorithm, this "code is shorter" but the algorithm is worse.

Comment: Right, it's far from optimal. But when you need min/max of small slice somewhere in middle of algorithm it's fine to sort it and take first/last instead of making separate function which you will never use again.

Comment: @fullpipe the slice is passed by value. Not the underlying data. It will be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Using @kostya's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34259943/5388438)

2. Use range loop:

   ```
   for i, e := range v {
       if i==0 || e < m {
           m = e
       }
   }
   ```

by not giving the index of value it will give you the minimum value 0, which may not be present in given values